# My offset function gets the error2042, it used to work, not it suddenly doesn't anymore..?

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting the error:

> c.Value = error2042

Can someone help? it used to work fine, now it doesn't work anymore.

```
Sub MecCapOvertime()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim LastRow As Long  
  
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("E1:E101")
        If c.Value = "MecCap" Then
            c.Offset(0, -2).Copy
            c.Offset(0, -3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        End If
    Next c
    
    Range("A1").Select
 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you getting MessageBox error? or your c.Value is equal to "error 2042" ? If c.Value is "error 2042" then check your Cell on which you getting this because it's probably #N/A

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/Concepts/Cells-and-Ranges/cell-error-values

Comment: Use `IsError` to test if the cell value is an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to replace `c.Value` with `c.Text`:

```
If c.Text = "MecCap" Then
```

When there is an error in the formula of the given Range then the `c.Value` will return an error.

Comment: That's not correct. If there is an error in any cell `c` then because it is compared with a string `c.Value = "MecCap"` the error in `c.Value` is implicitly cast into a string before to be able to compare it with the string `"MecCap"` and that does not cause an error. Also if you copy a cell with an error and paste it as value the error will just be cast into a string value.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - no. If the cell contains an error value, then `If c.Value = "MecCap" Then` will throw a type mismatch. Also, the error is not cast into a string value if you copy/paste as values. Tested with `=NA()` in a cell.

Comment: That said, using `.Text` has its own issues, and is not a reliable solution.

Comment: @BigBen my Fault. I wrote the error in column C instead of E ^^

Comment: @BigBen can you give me an example when this solution doesn't work with this kind of text-based comparrison? I have tested various scenarios and all worked fine for me. No offense btw, I'm just curious :-)

Comment: @MrZH6 - well `Range.Text` is more problematic when the cell contains a number, e.g. put 100000 in a cell, then shrink the cell width until it displays ##, then put `? ActiveCell.Text` in the Immediate Window; the result is `##`. I guess in this case if you're working with a `String` then you're probably fine.

Comment: @MrZH6 Not specific for this example but `c.Text` will use the number format of the cell to display numbers as text. That comes with issues for example if the number format is date and you use it in different countries where different dates are default. One country `c.Text` will show `2021-04-27` another might show `27.04.2021` so it is not reliable.

Comment: I would prefer to explicitly convert the value into a string `CStr(c.Value)` instead of `c.Text` because it does not touch the number format of the cell. And this also avoids the error 2042.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that there are cells in column E that contain errors. Compairing an error with a string causes a type mismatch because an error is type error and not type string.

The solution is to explicitly convert the error into a string with `cStr(c.Value)`:

```
If cStr(c.Value) = "MecCap" Then
```

Or to test for the error

```
If Not IsError(c.Value) Then
    If cStr(c.Value) = "MecCap" Then
        'your code here
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "There is an error in cell " & c.Address
End If
```